# Set View engine as PHP in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I Want to set View engine as PHP in Express project, and run PHP under node server

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");
var app = express();
var phpnode = require("php-node");

// All Routers
var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
// app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.engine("php", phpnode);
app.set("view engine", "php");
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,apikey");
//Auth Each API Request created by user.
next();
});
app.use("/", (res, req) => {
console.log("i m Root");
});
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

// render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my App.js file code. I want to run index.php in views folder. I'm developing web application in which I want to run an php file when I call root ("/") api.

Comment: Hey Welcome to Stackoverflow, check out the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maybe add more context and help us help you ;)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: How do envisage getting PHP to run under Node? If you want a PHP app to service part of your URL space, you may need to use a frontend proxy to forward web traffic based on a URL match. Traefik can do this.